# How can i apply kmeans?

Tags: python, data-science, data-mining

When i try this, i face with the error; ValueError: n_samples=6 should be >= n_clusters=7

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X=np.array([1,3,8,10,16,25])
X=X.reshape(-1,1)
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans= KMeans(n_clusters=3,init='k-means++')
kmeans.fit(X)

print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)

results=[]
for i in range(1,10):
    kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=i,init='k-means++',random_state=123)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    results.append(kmeans.inertia_)
```

Comment: Fixed with changing my range into (1,7)

Comment: This explains how you can use k-means method and may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62443970/k-means-clustering-for-word-vector-300-dimension/62445280#62445280

Answer (score 0):

You have 7 datapoints and you can not fit more then 7 clusters. You are trying to divide 7 people into 8 groups and so the error.

Check this

```
for i in range(1,10):
    kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=i,init='k-means++',random_state=123)
```

When `i==8` you will get the error.

Answer (score 0):

you are super close and 99% there. Nice job. You simply don't have enough distinct values in data, that's all:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X=np.array([1,3,8,10,16,25,1,3,8,10,16,25,44,55,66,77,88,99,12,13,14,15])
X=X.reshape(-1,1)
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans= KMeans(n_clusters=3,init='k-means++')
kmeans.fit(X)

print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)

results=[]
for i in range(1,10):
    kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=i,init='k-means++',random_state=123)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    results.append(kmeans.inertia_)
```

produces this output for me in PyCharm, Python 3.7.3:

```
[[88.  ]
 [11.25]
 [55.  ]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The example which is considered is a one-dimensional array with 6 points. But, you want to cluster for K until 10 then increase the number of data points in the X or set your range until the length of X.

```
X=np.array([1,3,8,10,16,25])
X=X.reshape(-1,1)
X.shape
(6, 1)
```

To,

```
X = np.linspace(1, 10, 50)
X=X.reshape(-1,1)
X.shape
(50, 1)
```